# Posting on LinkedIn and addressing a wider audience of roles

Tags: tone, social-media

I started posted on LinkedIn some time ago, and figured out that my content is suitable for a wider audience, and I am not sure I am able to capture that correctly.

I post various advice/tips/stories about tech and my intended audience spans from junior software engineers up to directors/vp(s). For example, the junior could only propose my improvements (because they have not much decision power), but the director/vp could actually implement the improvements I suggest (because they have the right decision power).

What would be the best way to address such a wide span of audience? How to best address so all can benefit (and share my posts)?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you planning to do, write a book? Write articles? Create a blog or website or something else with short texts? Or are you wanting to know that? Are you worried about language, style, tone, technique? Are you wanting to make individual points relevant to everyone or combine advice for different people? (As far as the audience goes, many people are interested in reading advice even if it doesn't directly apply to them, but it needs to be something that's interesting, surprising, or thought-provoking.)

Comment: I am not asking about places to publish or in what form to publish. I want to post on LinkedIn, and each post would consist in a couple of sentences of useful advice/information.

What I want is that is for whoever reads to know that "They can implement this right now in their company" (even if it means to pitch it to their superiors (juniors) or to do it themselves (directors/vps)). I think the last sentence from @StuartF is encouraging. I will make the posts interesting, surprising or thought provoking. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Most prolific LinkedIn posters I see start their posts by addressing their intended audience for that post directly. That is, their very first sentence will be:

> Dear **system administrators,**

Or,

> Hey there, **hiring managers.**

This immediately and effectively grabs the attention of the people who have the occupation(s) that the post is intended for, while allowing the non-intended audience to just pass it right by. As you say, most of your posts will be targeted higher up the chain, as junior developers don't have any deciding power to take on your suggestions (and, minor nitpick, I would call them *suggestions*, not just labeling them as objective improvements, to avoid coming across as extremely arrogant). Thus, you can start your posts by directly addressing: **"Dear senior developers/middle managers/CIOs/etc."**